SSIS How to convert date datatype with a size of 8 in source file with format yyyymmdd convert to yyyy-mm-dd
I am trying to load data to a SQL table using SSIS package. Text file has date columns in the format yyyymmdd, the SQL table has datatype set to date (has to remain as date), but when I'm using a derive column to do the conversion it keeps throwing errors.
I've tried using the following:
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([DATE_Column1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([DATE_Column],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([DATE_Column],7,2)). however, it is not working.
Keeps throwing errors like "an error occurred while attempting to do a type cast.
Sample of text file:

I've tried all variations of type cast for converting to date field in derive column. It may have null or blank values for the date columns - i just don know how to account for that. Any insight, assistance will be greatly appreciated.

It looks like there was a missing bracket and comma in your expression.  Try:
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([DATE_Column],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([DATE_Column],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([DATE_Column],7,2))

Formatted for clarity:
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)
    (
         SUBSTRING([DATE_Column], 1, 4)
         + "-" + 
         SUBSTRING([DATE_Column], 5, 2) 
         + "-" + 
         SUBSTRING([DATE_Column], 7, 2)
     )


thanks, but I think it was typo here.... the version you gave is the same using in derive column

I've tried the following (DT_WSTR)[PROCESSED_DT]== "" ? NULL(DT_WSTR) : PROCESSED_DT == (DT_WSTR,8)00000000 ? (DT_WSTR,4)LEFT(PROCESSED_DT,4) + "-" + (DT_WSTR,2)SUBSTRING(PROCESSED_DT,5,2) + "-" + (DT_WSTR,2)SUBSTRING(PROCESSED_DT,7,2)... but it is not populating "NULL" when there's a blank value in the date field.

Your expression in the question has a type on the reference to the date column - there is no bracket or comma: SUBSTRING([DATE_Column1,4), but maybe this was just in the question itself.  It looks like your problem is with some of the data which is throwing type cast errors, but would work the rest of the time.  You can test this by only sending in a few valid dates to see if your expression works.  Let me know if I understand the problem correctly.

Thanks,  came back to share i was able to figure it out... this solved it for me PROCESSED_DT == (DT_WSTR,8)"" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,10) : (DT_WSTR,4)LEFT(PROCESSED_DT,4) + "-" + (DT_WSTR,2)SUBSTRING(PROCESSED_DT,5,2) + "-" + (DT_WSTR,2)SUBSTRING(PROCESSED_DT,7,2)... thanks for your time, much appreciated!
